# Change the background color and text color with a timer with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, colors, setinterval

I'm trying to change both the background and text color of a table and all its cells with a timer.  I have the script below just before the end  tag.  The background is the only thing that changes.  The id of the table is 'titleTable'. Thanks

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!-- Begin
titleTable.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
setInterval("Timer()", 500);
x=1;
function Timer() {
    set=1;
    if(x==0 && set==1) {
        titleTable.bgColor='#000000';
        titleTable.style.color='#FFFFFF';
        x=1;
        set=0;
    }
    if(x==1 && set==1) {
        titleTable.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
        titleTable.style.color='#000000';
        x=0;
        set=0;
    }
}
// End -->
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you do have, to make it easier to trouble shoot where the issue is taking place.

Comment: You can format code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: Are you sure the background color changes? The code to change background color is this, titleTable.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'. Also how are u grabbing the DOM Element for titleTable? document.getElementById? Please post the full code.

Comment: this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455485/how-change-background-color-of-html-elements-with-javascript-in-a-certain-time-p/25455719#25455719

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var s = document.getElementById('titleTable').style,
        f = false,
        c1 = '#000000',
        c2 = '#ffffff';

    setInterval(function() {
        s.backgroundColor = f ? c1 : c2;
        s.color = f ? c2 : c1;
        f = !f;
    }, 500);
})();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dzk2h/2/

Just put the above code inside a `<script>` element at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Thanks for attaching that script.. helped me find what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

var titleTable = document.getElementById('titleTable');

if(x==0 && set==1)
->
if((x==0) && (set==1))

Just use "blink" tag =)

Ah, "The background is the only thing that changes".
Check styles. If you have CSS rule like

```
#titleTable td { color: black; }
```

It will not be overriden by setting inline style to the table.

Comment: Ah, yes! This was it.  I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Just for anyone else that has problems with this, apparently you cannot edit pseudo tags for html with javascript globally. For instance, there is no way (that I've found) that you can edit all h1 tags style properties. Instead, you have to give that tag a unique id and edit it with javascript from there.

Comment: Of course )
But there's a way for manipulating CSS rules from js.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_3:_Manipulating_Styles