# Change background color of HTML elements with JavaScript in a certain time period?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, timer

I have around 26 html elements for which I want the following effect in JavaScript:

[image: animation]

Is it possible to make something like this?

I was trying to do it as follows:

```
var j = 2000;
        for (i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
            setInterval(function() {document.getElementById('Q' + i).style.backgroundColor = '#00a300'}, j);
            setInterval(function() {document.getElementById('Q' + i).style.color = '#FFFFFF'}, j);
            j = j + j;
            setInterval(function() {document.getElementById('Q' + (i-1)).style.backgroundColor = '#e1e1e1'}, j);
            setInterval(function() {document.getElementById('Q' + (i-1)).style.color = '#666666'}, j);
        }
```

I am a novice with JavaScript and have never worked with timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have constructed a little fiddle example using jQuery.animate function, and jQuery color plugin to create fade animations of background color.

Please find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nafm74yd/15/

Please notice there is one external resource used in the left hand panel of the jsfiddle... it points to the jQuery color plugin to its CDN.

the script is something like this:

```
    function animate(idx) {
        $($('.block')[idx]).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff0000" }, 200, function () {
            var idx2 = idx;
            $($('.block')[idx2]).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 200, function () {});
            if (idx >= $('.block').length - 1) {
                setTimeout(animate(0), 200);
            } else setTimeout(animate(idx + 1), 200);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        animate(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### css

```css
div {
    display:block;
    background:black;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

#### html

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div>....
```

#### js

```js
function animateStuff(domElements, baseColor, activeColor, delay) {
    var count=0;
    var animationRun=1;
    var frames=0;
    function frame() {
        frames++;

        if((frames%delay)==1){//set delay only animate on loops that the set delay has past.
            count++;
            if(count>=domElements.length){
                count=0;//back to the beginning of the loop.
            }
            // make all the divs black
            for(var x=0;x<domElements.length;x++){
                domElements[x].style.backgroundColor=baseColor;
            }
            // make one red
            domElements[count].style.backgroundColor=activeColor;
        }

        if(animationRun){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        }
    }
    frame();
}
//get an array of elements to animate.
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
//call animation and pass in the array of elements along with a few color settings and the delay.
animateStuff(elements,"black","red",100);
```

RequestAnimationFrame() will give you a consistent ~60fps on average. It also stops the animation loop when the tab is not being displayed. The animation starts when the tab is being displayed. `(frames%delay)==1` is to slow down the animation so its visible.

A good example of using this method is a javascript game engine i made source available here. https://github.com/Patrick-W-McMahon/Jinx-Engine

Comment: I believe that your answer it works, but in my case it gives error in the 3 browsers that I'm testing (IE, Firefox, Chrome), in Firefox gives me the error `too much recursion` and both chrome and IE ir gives me `Maximum call stack size exceeded ` I think I have too many dom elements...

Comment: Window.requestAnimationFrame() passes the function to be rendered by the systems hardware. This lets the OS handle the loop and still give time to other application on the system. It is running a loop as long as animationRun==true. It would only be giving you an error about the execution time if your not using window.requestAnimationFrame().

Comment: if you want a more detailed example of animation please review my source code located on the link i provided in my example.

Comment: setTimeout() should not be used anymore for animation all future animation should use window.requestAnimationFrame() as it passes animation loops to the systems OS letting the OS properly handle the loop and still manage normal operations of the system. a mistake with setTimeout() and you will end up getting the errors "too much recursion" and "Maximum call stack size exceeded". do not use setTimeout() to do animation loops.

Comment: I have updated my example to show it being used on an html page so you can see that it is working. The error you had is due to a small typo that I made when I was typing it in. You will see this example works best and is the correct answer.

Comment: @FranciscoCosta I think the error might be introduced elsewhere. I modified the code a bit to move upwards (and a bit quicker) instead, and with 26 elements. Seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jt7tzr4L/2/ tested in ff, chrome and ie