# Changing dynamically CSS DIV Background every certain time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't see to make this work. I want to change the background of a div every certain time (every 7 seconds or so). I searched more answers here on StackOverflow but couldn't find a correct solution.

```
<div id="head">
content
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#head{
background:#181015 url( ../images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
min-height:520px; 
}
```

Im pretty sure it's with Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925099/change-the-background-color-and-text-color-with-a-timer-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` function to change the image each X seconds and array to store the url's:

**HTML**

```
<div id="head">
 content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#head {
  background:#181015 url( ../images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  min-height:520px; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var head = document.getElementById('head'),
images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'],
i = 0;

setInterval(function(){

  if (i === images.length) i = 0;

  head.style.background = '#181015 url( ../images/' + images[i] + ') no-repeat';

  i++;

}, 3000);
```